# Ball bounce in 3d

Tags: 3d, vector, collision-resolution, sphere

I cannot get my bounce equations right. I have 2 spheres, that can colide at any angle. One is forever stationary, other one is moving though the space.

I have X,Y,Z speed of the moving ball and a nomalised vector in direction of stationary ball.

Obvious idea was

ballSpeedX *= -1;

ballSpeedY *= -1;

ballSpeedZ *= -1;

Ofcourse that only works with head on colisions, but with side colisions, it bounces in wrong direction.

ballSpeedX *= -vectorX;

ballSpeedY *= -vectorY;

ballSpeedZ *= -vectorZ;

Also wrong :D

Comment: Do you have the exact position the 2 ball collides at? If you do, then this'll be a piece of cake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flipping the velocity vector across a normal alone is not a very good way to model velocity after a collision but if you'd like to do it anyways. All you need is the reflection vector. Here's the vector d reflected across some normal n to get r. (Note the difference between dot product and component product.)

[image]

[image]

In your case d is v and r is the resulting velocity. Getting n is entirely based off the surface that is hit. For two spheres you can just subtract the centers of the circles and normalize it to get a unit vector n.

Like I said this is not a good way to respond to the collision as it doesn't account for the mass of the objects in the collision, the velocity of the objects in the collision, or the energy lost in the collision. I'd look into momentum if I were you. In fact the type of collision modeled in the above example assumes no energy loss, the same masses, and the same velocities in equal and opposite directions.

This equation represents all the variables you would need in a collision like this.
[image]

p is change in momentum, m is mass, e is elasticity (energy loss/bounciness), and n is the collision normal.